# Django run manage.py generates OS error in OS X Yosemite

Tags: python, django, osx-yosemite

I'm having problem with running Django manage.py runserver on my MAC OS X Yosemite.

When I ran it soon after restarting, everything works fine. But after several minutes, the running process will stop, and when I re-rerun manage.py runserver, it will generate this error

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 22, 2015 - 15:10:11
Django version 1.7.3, using settings 'mycustomapp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Users/fendy/.virtualenvs/mycustomapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Users/fendy/.virtualenvs/mycustomapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Users/fendy/.virtualenvs/mycustomapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/Users/fendy/.virtualenvs/mycustomapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Users/fendy/.virtualenvs/mycustomapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 83, in handle
self.run(*args, **options)
File "/Users/fendy/.virtualenvs/mycustomapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in run
autoreload.main(self.inner_run, args, options)
File "/Users/fendy/.virtualenvs/mycustomapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 322, in main
reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
File "/Users/fendy/.virtualenvs/mycustomapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 288, in python_reloader
reloader_thread()
File "/Users/fendy/.virtualenvs/mycustomapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 264, in reloader_thread
change = fn()
File "/Users/fendy/.virtualenvs/mycustomapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 202, in code_changed
stat = os.stat(filename)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './manage.py'
```

Note that I am in the same directory as manage.py does. but for some reasons, it could not find it

here is what I found when I run ls:
manage.py       requirements.txt    mycustomapp

My django version is 1.7.3, OS YOSEMITE, I had all brew updated and upgraded

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks !

Comment: How do you execute `manage.py`?

Comment: the usual way, in the directory where manage.py file exists, just run " ./manage.py runserver" , note that the same goes for "python manage.py runserver", I've been developing websites with django for 2 years, and now I had no idea why did I get this error. my other web apps works fine, but they uses Django 1.5 version

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the issue. Turns out since in this Django version I would need to separate the wsgi file for development and production use. therefore wsgi_prod.py and wsgi.py . This action was not needed in previous versions of Django.

Comment: Fendy, would you be so kind to provide a sample code of both files? I don't get what's the reason of the issue.

Comment: Did someone has a solution for this problem? @PavelDaynyak?

Comment: @SergiuZaharie, I moved to python3.4 and django 1.10. Probably, it was a kind of an environment problem, don't face it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to upgrade or degrade your Django version for an OSError [Error123].
I got this error for weeks and I thought about the actual reason behind this error because my code and files were all perfect! But then, after weeks of observation of my code, I figured out the hell of that mistake!

ANSWER - Please create your APPS, STATIC-FOLDER, TEMPLATE-FOLDER, and further things within your PROJECT!!

DEMONSTRATION -> { '>>' indicates next step}

```
OPEN POWERSHELL >> mkdir DIRECTORY_NAME >> cd DIRECTORY_NAME >> code .

this will open visual studio code within the directory named (DIRECTORY_NAME)

OPEN TERMINAL >> install django >> django startproject PROJECT_NAME >>
cd PROJECT_NAME >> python manage.py runserver >> COME OUT OF THE SERVER >> django startapp APP_NAME >> CONTINUE YOUR WORK IN THE VS CODE AND ONLY COM TO TERMINAL TO RUN SERVER.
```